# Can i back multiple ingress class' with one ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Hoping someone here can help.
I have a use case, where I am exposing an NGINX ingress controller with both internal and external LBs. The internal LB is used for things that sit outside of K8S, but within the same network to talk via ingress to things inside K8S, whilst still leveraging our NGINX configurations.

The challenge :

I want to be able to restrict endpoints which we are exposing only to internal systems, so that they can not be accessed via the external LBs (it would be pretty easy for someone to hit the external LB with the correct host headers otherwise and still access the applications behind them).

Does anyone know of any way to do this, which does not involve having to stand up a duplicate NGINX deployment entirely. IE, was hoping to be able to have an ingress class defined which would use exclusively the service with the internal LB rather than the external one.